# get start day of week and end day fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, laravel-5.8, fullcalendar-5

I´m traying to get actual week with `fullCalendar` plugin in `laravel 5.8`. I need get it, to send this date to controller and to do a query with this date.

In my script.js i have a `listener click` but change my view to week and in this view in title put current week in this format:

```
8 – 14 mar 2021
```

i want to get firts day of week and last day of week. Also i´m traying with

```
var currentDate = calendar
var beginOfWeek = currentDate.startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = currentDate.endOf('week');
```

but returned me:

```
currentDate.startOf is not a function
```

because `currentData` return empty array... But i´m instaciate my calendar so:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridDay dayGridWeek dayGridMonth listMonth'
    },
    locale: config.lang,
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    displayEventTime: true,
    
    events: dbEvents,
```

and i have all my events from DB in my calendar... I don´t understand why i can´t use my object to use `startOf` and `endOf`.

I don´t know i´m doing well my logic, maybe i should to do this to other form. How can i get current week? and even i want show next or last week that i can get this week ok.

Thanks so much for help, and sorry for my english i hope that you can understand me.

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc, fullCalendar does not have a `startOf` or `endOf` week. I'm not sure what you were trying to do there, or what you were expecting to happen, or why? You could try `calendar.view.activeStart` and `calendar.view.activeEnd` instead - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Comment: However, I would actually recommend that you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed so that you can define a dynamic event source, and have fullCalendar refresh the events automatically whenever the view or the date changes. It will automatically send the correct start and end dates to your server so that your server can return the required events correctly. And you don't have to worry about getting those dates yourself, or triggering the refresh. If you wanted to trigger a refresh from your own code though, you'd run https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your response, just i need this!!! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with this function, i´m able to get week´s days

```
/** GET DAYS OF WEEK */
  function getDaysOfWeek(calendar){
    if(!calendar) return;
    let startDayWeek = calendar.view.activeStart;
    let endDayWeek = calendar.view.activeEnd;

    var firstDay = new Date(startDayWeek);
    var lastDay = new Date(endDayWeek);

    dayStartWeek = firstDay.toISOString().substring(0,10);
    dayEndWeek = lastDay.toISOString().substring(0,10);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made like this because some end month wasn´t works properly:

```
function getDaysOfWeek(){
    var calendar = calendarRef.current.getApi();
    let startDayWeek = calendar.view.currentStart;
    let endDayWeek = calendar.view.currentEnd;
    var firstDay = new Date(startDayWeek);
    var lastDay = new Date(endDayWeek);
    firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
    lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() - 2);
console.log(firstDay.toISOString().substring(0,10),lastDay.toISOString().substring(0,10));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).